# In backend: how to get checkboxed items id?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, backend

How I can get ids of checked items in items list in backend. I want add extra functionality to `publish` function. So what I need is to get that checked ids. In (com_registracijos\controllers\lists.php) I tried add something likes this:

```
function publish() 
{
$id = JRequest::getInt('id');
$value = JRequest::getInt('value');
$boxchecked = JRequest::getInt('boxchecked');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ids of a list checked itemsyou should get and array instead of an int:

```
$arrayIDs = JRequest::getVar ( 'cid', null, 'default', 'array' );
```

Please, note that **cid** is the name of the check.

Every component, if any, of the resulting array is a checked item id.

If you need a sample, you may check [delete uploaded file from an array of id when they are delted in joomla?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703515/delete-uploaded-file-from-an-array-of-id-when-they-are-delted-in-joomla) It is doing a delete, but it will give you the idea.

Regards,